Values of k for which the equation $4^{x}-k\cdot2^{x}-k+3=0$ has at least one positive solution.
My attempt:
$4^{x}-k\cdot2^{x}-k+3=0$
Assuming $2^x=t>0$, $$f(t)=t^2-tk-k+3$$
We can say,
if x is +ve, $t \in (1,\infty)$
if x is -ve, $t \in (0,1)$
Now I took two conditions,

$t>0$

$$D\geq0 \;\;\cap\;\;\alpha + \beta >0\;\;\cap\;\;\alpha*\beta>0$$
which gives $k\in[2,3)$

At least one root belongs to $(1,\infty)$

Conditions for both roots belonging to $(0,1)$:
$$D\geq0\;\;\cap\;\;af(0)>0\;\;\cap\;\;af(0)>1\;\;\cap\;\;0<\frac{-b}{2a}<1$$
which gives $k\in \phi$
So, for at least one root to belong to $(1,\infty)$, $\;k\in R-\phi$
So, in conclusion $k\in [2,3) \cap R$
$k\in [2,3)$
However, the answer is actually $k\in (2,\infty)$

Some parts above seem unclear.  You need positive solutions, so $x>0 \implies t>1$, hence case 1 is not what you want.  Further, if $S$ contains solutions for $k$ s.t. two roots are there in $(0, 1)$, how do you conclude $\mathbb R-S$ as the set for which at least one root belongs to $(1, \infty)$?

@Macavity I see the first case is somewhat wrong. The second part however, $\mathbb R-S$ is intersected with the set for $t>0$ which I assumed would give us the set for which at least one root belongs to $(1,\infty)$.

The solutions for $t=2^x>1$ (as $x>0$) are
$$
t_{1,2}=\frac{k\pm\sqrt{k^2+4k-12}}2=\frac{k\pm\sqrt{(k-2)(k+6)}}2.
$$
So the solution exists iff $k\ge 2$ or $k\le -6$.
If $k> 2$, then the largest solution $>1$.
If $k\le -6$,  the largest solution is negative. So the answer is $k> 2$.

This maybe simpler by just completing squares.
$4f(t)=(2t-k)^2-k^2-4k+12$, so $f=0 \implies (2t-k)^2=k^2+4k-12$, therefore we need $2t=k\pm\sqrt{(k+2)^2-16}>2$.
It suffices to consider the larger root, and for the root to be real we need $k\geqslant 2$ or $k\leqslant -6$. Then it is easily seen $k>2$ is the only solution.

Another approach.
Starting from your $f(t)$, consider the function
$$k(t)=\frac{t^2+3}{t+1}\qquad \text{with} \qquad t>1$$ Differentiating
$$k'(t)=\frac{t^2+2 t-3}{(t+1)^2}=\frac{(t-1) (t+3)}{(t+1)^2}$$ So, the first derivative can cancel only for $t=1$.
The second derivative test shows that this is a minimum $(k''(1)=1)$ and $k(1)=2$. So, there is a positive (non-zero) solution $\forall k>2$.

We can write above equation as
$\displaystyle k(2^x+1)=4^x+3=(4^x-1)+4$
$\displaystyle k=2^x-1+\frac{4}{2^x+1}$
$\displaystyle k=\underbrace{2^x+1+\frac{4}{2^x+1}}_{\text{A.M>= G.M}}-2\geq 2(2)-2=2$
And equality hold when
$\displaystyle 2^x+1=\frac{4}{2^x+1}\Longrightarrow 2^x+1=2\Longrightarrow x=0$
For at least one positive roots , $\displaystyle \color{blue}{k\in\bigg(2,\infty\bigg)}$
